# How do I convert a bunch of linear layouts to one relative layout

Tags: java, android-layout, layout

I have been trying to learn how to use relative layouts in Android Studios. I have only made layouts with a bunch of linear layouts inside of them and all of the tutorials I have seen display how to put a text view in the top right corner, center, bottom left etc...but I want to know how I can place things in any location to convert a bunch of linear layouts to one relative layout(example: Place something 1/3 down the parent view) and things like that but I have had no luck finding information on that. Thanks to anyone who helps in advanced!

Comment: What have you tried? Have you done research on how to use relative layout and are stuck, or do you just want us to do your work for you?

Comment: @nhouser9 oh no no, maybe i worded this bad. I just want to know how I would go about doing this because I have been watching tutorials, but they are all just placing a box in the middle of the parent, the very left, right etc...I want to know how can I place things like 1/3 down in the parent and still have it resize and things like that(I am going to reword my question so people to don't confused, sorry about that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use **Relativelayout** and **Linearlayout** futures you can use **PercentRelativelayout** like this

```
    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <ImageView
         app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
         app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
         app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
         app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"/>
 </android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>
```

you need dependency of it

```
compile 'com.android.support:percent:24.1.1'
```

Comment: Thank you! That is what I am now using, it is working and resizing however the buttons are now touching each other when they resize do you have any clue as to how I could make it so they keep a certain distance % between each other?

Comment: if I correctly understood what you want, you can take one button position by relative to another, for example you can define constraints, 
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/another_view_id" then app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"/> or something like that...

Answer (score 0):

The thing which you want to achieve is more possible from LinearLayout, as it supports "weight" property. 
RelativeLayout on the other side, as the name suggests lets you to place your views in relation to other views or parent.